# trouble with csv reader in python 2

Tags: python, csv

I am having trouble getting python 2 to loop through a .csv file. The code bellow is throwing the error:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     for row in reader:
...             print row
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

The python 3 version of this works fine but I need this to run for 2. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `open('test.csv', 'rU')`? What is in your csv file?

Comment: That worked thanks. It was just a list of addresses. What does the U do that fixed it?

Comment: I will add an answer with some links, too long to write as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open using `open('test.csv', 'rU')`

**universal newlines**

relevant info from the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines):

*A manner of interpreting text streams in which all of the following are recognized as ending a line: the Unix end-of-line convention '\n', the Windows convention '\r\n', and the old Macintosh convention '\r'. See PEP 278 and PEP 3116, as well as str.splitlines() for an additional use*

and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

*In addition to the standard fopen() values mode may be 'U' or 'rU'. Python is usually built with universal newlines support; supplying 'U' opens the file as a text file, but lines may be terminated by any of the following: the Unix end-of-line convention '\n', the Macintosh convention '\r', or the Windows convention '\r\n'. All of these external representations are seen as '\n' by the Python program. If Python is built without universal newlines support a mode with 'U' is the same as normal text mode. Note that file objects so opened also have an attribute called newlines which has a value of None (if no newlines have yet been seen), '\n', '\r', '\r\n', or a tuple containing all the newline types seen.*

Comment: Thanks for the help. Couldn't find this in at python.org so glad I came here.